# Why majority voting in this case works?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning

Suppose y is a target variable of k categories and size m. The distribution of k is unknown. And suppose there is a system that tells you your accuracy each time you make a prediction. You randomly generate prediction from uniform distribution of k, and save the prediction that has accuracy higher than 0.5. After doing it many many times, you make the final prediction by majority voting of those prediction you saved. You will always get 100% accuracy this way.

Why does this work? What is the theory/math behind this?

Comment: You will overfit to whatever set of data the oracle is using to measure the accuracy.